# How do you tell if the message is from send or sendSync in the main process?

Tags: electron

in the main process, ipcMain.on received the message is from `send` or `sendSync`?

```js
ipcMain.on('eventName', (event, arg) => {
  if ( /* ??? */ ) {
    event.sender.send('AsyncEventName', arg)
  } else {
    event.returnValue = arg
  }
})
```

Comment: You could use different event channels for async and sync as illustrated in [the ipcMain docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main). Do you have restrictions that don't allow you to do that? If yes, if you add them to your question you will get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in a value into `send` to make the distinction:

```
ipcRenderer.send("eventName", myArg, true);
ipcRenderer.sendSync("eventName", myArg, false);
```

And then in your main code:

```
ipcMain.on('eventName', (event, arg, isAsync) => {
    if (isAsync) {
        event.sender.send('AsyncEventName', arg)
    } else {
        event.returnValue = arg
    }
});
```

---

The other option is to use two different channels:

```
ipcRenderer.send("eventName", myArg);
ipcRenderer.sendSync("eventNameSync", myArg);
```

And then in your main code:

```
ipcMain.on('eventName', (event, arg) => {
    event.sender.send('AsyncEventName', arg)
});
ipcMain.on('eventNameSync', (event, arg) => {
    event.returnValue = arg
});
```

Personally, I prefer the second one.

Comment: I would like to know the difference between `events` in `ipcMain.on` through `send` and `sendSync`, or they are the same ?

Comment: Well, `ipcMain` accepts an event of type `Electron.Event` (assuming you're using TypeScript) regardless of how it's called. It is described [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#event-object), and it looks like they're the same. They just have a `sender` and a `returnValue` property.